# Click on Camera Shutter using UIAutomator

Tags: android-camera, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I am writing an Espresso test for my app, and am trying to automate clicking the shutter button after opening of a camera in my app.

I am using Espresso and UIAutomator in the Android Emulator. I managed to dump this UI in UIAutomatorViewer. [image: UIAutomatorViewer]

I can't figure out why I am unable to click on the shutter button using UIAutomator using this code:

```
public void clickCameraShutterButton() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
{
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    UiSelector shutterSelector = new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.camera:id/shutter_button");
    UiObject shutterButton = device.findObject(shutterSelector);
    shutterButton.click();
}
```

The camera just sits there, and the shutter button is never clicked. This is the stack trace I'm getting in the Android Studio monitor:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Initialize UiDevice instance
    final Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation);
}

...


/**
 * @@Test comment here@@
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Test
public void culebraGeneratedTest_CameraShutter() throws Exception {
    mDevice.findObject(By.res("com.android.camera2:id/shutter_button").desc("Shutter").clazz("android.widget.ImageView").text(Pattern.compile("")).pkg("com.android.camera2")).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
}
```

This test finds the shutter and clicks on it.

If you are interested this test was automatically generated using [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
device.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.camera:id/shutter_button")).click();
```

or

```
device.findObject(new UiSelector().description("Shutter button")).click();
```

or

```
device.executeShellCommand("input keyevent 27");
```

this mean KEYCODE_CAMERA value is 27

or

```
device.click(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to put the UI Automator Viewer "resource-id" value at the place of *

mdevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("*")).click();

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code below and it's working on a Google Pixel device.

```
fun captureImage() {
    val instrument = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
    val device = UiDevice.getInstance(instrument)
    // camera clicked 
    device.executeShellCommand("input keyevent 27")
    // save button clicked 
    device.findObject(By.res("com.android.camera2:id/done_button")).click()
}
```

to cancel the image use "com.android.camera2:id/cancel_button"